# Ratio of two weighted sum of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, resampling

Given a vector $X=(x_1,\dots x_N) \in R_+^N$ and $N$ i.i.d Bernoulli random variable $A_i$ with $$P(A_i= 1)=p = 1 -P(A_i = 0)$$

First we define the random variable $T$ as
$$
T = \frac{\sum_{i}x_i * A_i}{\sum_i A_i}
$$

If we let $0/0 = 0$, then $T$ should be an unbiased estimator of the sample mean of $X$, that is $E[T] = \sum_{i} x_i/n$. I am wondering if there is any closed form formula to express the variance of $T$? Any upper bound on the variance in terms of $N$ is also helpful here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### In Short

A variation of this problem has been described by Grab and Savage (1954) 'Tables of the Expected Value of 1/X for Positive Bernoulli and Poisson Variables' [JASA Vol. 49, No. 265](https://doi.org/10.2307/2281043)

> The following situation often arises in sampling problems. An observation $y_i \, (i=1, \cdots x)$ is made of $x$ individuals and the average, $$Y = (y_1 + y_2 + \dots + y_x)/x,$$ is computed.
>
> If the $y_i$'s are independent observations on a random variable with mean value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, we find that the mean value of $Y$ is $\mu$. However, if $x$, the sample size, is a random variable, then the variance of $Y$ is not $\sigma^2/x$ but it is $\sigma^2E(1/x)$.

---

#### Long

With the definition $0/0 = 0$ it becomes a bit difficult because this will give some probability that $T=0$. Below I will consider the problem as truncated such that you never have $\sum A_i =0$ or $T=0$.

Your problem is equivalent to sampling from $X$ without repetition, and taking the mean of the sample, where the sample size $n$ is determined by a binomial distribution.

If $X$ is very large in comparison to the sample size then you can estimate this by sampling *with* repetition.

In that approximation you can compute the variance by considering the moments conditional on the sample size $n = \sum A_n$. The variance scales like $\frac{Var(X)}{n}$ and the total variance will be a sum of those variances for different $n$ * $$Var(T) \approx Var(X) \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-1}{Pr}\left[\sum A_i = n\right] = Var(T)E(n^{-1})$$

For this expectation of $n^{-1}$, I have not an easy solution. Of course, you can simply compute it as a sum, but when $N$ becomes large you might want to have some expression to estimate it. I have created a separate question for this: [Expectation of negative moment $E[k^{-1}]$ for zero-truncated Poisson distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515197/)

#### Simulation

Below is a comparison using the integral expression for $E(n^{-1})$ from the other question. I used $X = \lbrace{1,2,\dots,1000\rbrace}$. It illustrates that it works for smaller $p$. the discrepancy between the computation and simulation at higher $p$ is due to the approximation of sampling without repetition by sampling with repetition.

[image: comparison of simulation with computation for different values of p]

```r
x = 1:1000
n = length(x)
p = 0.01
lambda = n*p

#### compute estimate
compVar <- function() {
  var_x = mean(x^2)-mean(x)^2
  E_inv_n = exp(-lambda)/(1-exp(-lambda))*(expint::expint_Ei(lambda)-log(lambda)-0.57721)
  ### result = 94.17509
  E_inv_n*var_x
}

### Simulate 

sim <- function() {
  a <- rbinom(n,1,p) ## Bernoulli variable
  result <- sum(a*x)/sum(a)
  return(result)
}

simVar <- function() {
  n_sim <- 10^4
  T_sim <- replicate(n_sim,sim())
  return(mean(T_sim^2, na.rm = TRUE)-mean(T_sim, na.rm = TRUE)^2)
}


### compare for different values of p

sim_v <- c()
comp_v <- c()

set.seed(1)
prng <- 10^seq(-2,-0.2,0.2)
for (ps in prng) {
  p = ps
  lambda = n*p
  sim_v <- c(sim_v,simVar())
  comp_v <- c(comp_v,compVar())
}


plot(prng,comp_v, log = 'xy',
     xlab = expression(P*(A[i] == 0)),
     ylab = "variance", type = "l", ylim = c(3*10^1,10^4), xlim = c(0.01,1),
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
points(prng,sim_v, pch = 21 , col = 1, bg = 0)

logaxis <- function(pos,order,tck = -0.005, las = 1) {
  axis(pos, at = 10^order, las = las)
  for (subord in order[-1]) {
    axis(pos, at = 0.1*10^subord*c(1:9),labels=rep("",9), tck = tck)
  }
}

logaxis(pos = 1, order = c(-3:0))
logaxis(pos = 2, order = c(1:4), las = 2)


legend(0.01,100,c("simulation","computed"), lty = c(0,1), pch = c(21,NA))
```

---

* (note that this simple computation of the variance of the compound distribution works because the mean is the same I every condition)